# Performance ao Rendenizar Páginas ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Como posso ter maior performance para rendenizar minhas páginas usando ASP.NET MVC ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A performance de renderização de uma View está relacionada com uma série de aspectos:

- Desempenho do Controller;
- Quantidade de Filtros e Interceptadores envolvendo sua aplicação;
- Quantidade de JavaScript colocada na `View` e no Layout da `View`.

Não existe um roteiro para melhorar a performance que seja canônico, mas posso tentar reunir nesta resposta uma série de medidas para melhorar a performance das suas `Views`:

## 1. Retirar `ViewEngines` que não serão usados

No seu arquivo `Global.asax.cs`, use os seguintes comandos:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());
```

Para este caso, você usará apenas o Razor. Se você estiver usando WebForms, use:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new WebFormViewEngine());
```

## 2. Forçar o uso do `[OutputCache]` para páginas estáticas

Por exemplo:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [OutputCache]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       return View();
    }
}
```

Se a página muda pouco, guardá-la em cache pode ser uma boa solução para evitar o uso do motor de renderização quando isso não é necessário.

## 3. Retirar informações de Debug das Views em Produção

Ao publicar seu sistema em produção, certifique-se de que seu `Web.config` tenha anotado o seguinte:

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.0" debug="false">
```

## 4. Usar *Eager Load* para `Views` que usam muitas informações dependentes

Essa é válida para sistemas que utilizem algum framework de banco de dados com carga preguiçosa (*Lazy Load*), como o Entity Framework e o nHibernate.

Por exemplo, se carrego uma Pessoa (normalmente uma entidade com muitos dados agregados), devo apressar a carga das informações, evitando que o *Lazy Load* cause um gargalo de desempenho.

```
var pessoa = context.Pessoas.Include(p => p.Enderecos)
                            .Include(p => p.Telefones)
                            .Include(p => p.Compras)
                            .Include(p => p.Dependentes)
                            .Single(p => p.PessoaId == pessoaId);
```

Comment: Porque do debug="false"?

Comment: `debug="false"` retira as informações de Debug, que consomem algum processamento para serem incluídas na requisição.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez quando compila em "release" ele já coloca o debug=false não?

Comment: Depende da configuração. Se o Web.config passa por transformação, sim.